# C++. Дружественные функции. Перегруженные операции

Tags: c++

Возникло парочка проблем с заданием, надеюсь на помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается сделать умножение 2х матриц. И не понятно как делать меню для проверки

**Header.h**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class matrix {

private:
    int n, m;
    double ** matr;

public:
    matrix(int, int); //конструктор с параметрами

    matrix(const matrix& ob);   //конструктор копирования
    ~matrix(void);        //деструктор

                          //функции-элементы изменения закрытых данных
    void set();

    //функции-элементы чтения закрытых данных
    void get(void);
    void trans(void);

    //операция индексации
    double& operator()(int, int);
    //операция присваивания массивов
    const matrix &operator=(const matrix &);
    //операция сложения массивов
    matrix &operator+(const matrix &);

    //операция вставки в поток
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, matrix ob);
    //операция извлечения из потока
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &stream, matrix &ob);


};

matrix::matrix(int a, int b)
{
    n = a;
    m = b;
    matr = new double *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        matr[i] = new double[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            matr[i][j] = 0;
}

//конструктор копирования
matrix::matrix(const matrix& ob)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            matr[i][j] = ob.matr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

/*
//конструктор преобразования
Rusmoney::Rusmoney(int in100)
{//изменяем только значение поля n100
n001=0, n005=0, n01=0, n05=0, n1=0, n2=0, n5=0, n10=0, n50=0, n100=0, n500=0, n1000=0, n5000=0;
n100=in100;
}


//конструктор преобразования
Rusmoney::Rusmoney(char* fam)
{    name=new char[strlen(fam)+1];
strcpy(name,fam);
//используем значение поля number по умолчанию
number=555;
cout<<"constructor preobrazovania "<<name<<endl;
}*/

//деструктор
matrix::~matrix(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete matr[i];

    delete[]matr;
}



void matrix::set()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            cin >> matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void matrix::get(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            cout << matr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void matrix::trans()
{
    double ** buf = new double *[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        buf[i] = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            buf[j][i] = matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            cout << buf[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

#include "Overload.h"
```

Overload.h

```
//Перегруженная операция индексации
double & matrix::operator()(int i, int j)
{
    //проверка ошибочного выхода индекса из диапазона
    if (i<0 || j<0 || i >= n || j >= m)
    {
        cout << "Error index!\n";  exit(1);
    }

    //возвращение ссылки создает L-величину
    return matr[i][j];
}

// Перегруженная операция присваивания
const matrix & matrix::operator=(const matrix &right)
{
    if (&right != this)//проверка самоприсваивания
    {
        //возвращение области памяти
        delete[] matr;

        //изменение размера массива
        n = right.n;
        m = right.m;

        //выделение памяти для копии массива
        matr = new double *[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            matr[i] = new double[m];

        //массив копии в объект
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                matr[i][j] = right.matr[i][j];

        return *this;
    }
}

matrix & matrix::operator+(const matrix &right)
{
    if (n == right.n && m == right.m)
    {
        matrix buf(n, m);

        //массив копии в объект
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                buf.matr[i][j] = matr[i][j] + right.matr[i][j];

        return buf;
    }
    else
        cout << "Wrong dimensions!" << endl;
}


//Перегруженная операция извлечения из потока
istream &operator >> (istream &stream, matrix &ob)
{
    //ввод элементов массива 
    for (int i = 0; i < ob.n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ob.m; ++j)
        {
            stream >> ob.matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return stream;
}

//Перегруженная операция вставки в поток
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, matrix ob)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ob.n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ob.m; ++j)
        {
            stream << ob.matr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n, m, i, j;
    cout << "Введите число строк и столбцов в матрице:" << endl;
    cin >> n >> m;
    // Число строк и столбцов
    cout << endl;
    matrix t(n, m);
    matrix p(n, m);
    matrix y(n, m);

    t.get();
    p.get();

    t.set();
    p = t;
    y = p + t;

    t.get();
    p.get();
    y.get();

    t.trans();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Меню для проверки может выглядеть примерно так (лучше уточнить у преподавателя):

```
struct MatrixTest
{
    bool testAdd();
    bool testSub();
    bool testMul();
    ...
};
```

Умножение матриц:

```
void mul(int **A, int **B, int **C, int width, int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            int temp = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < height; ++k)
                temp += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

            C[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не могли бы вы показать, как сделать через switch?

Comment: Для наглядности: `enum {ADD, SUB, ...} tests;`. `switch (tests) { case ADD: /* Проверка сложения матриц */ break; case ...`

Comment: а как мне сделать так, чтобы в case 1 можно было создать матрицу, а в других саse с ней работать

Comment: Можно внутри `switch` перед первым `case`-ом. `switch (tests) {matrix m; case ADD: ... }`. Ну или ставить скобки после `case`: `switch (tests) { case ADD: {matrix m;} break; case SUB: {matrix m;} ... }`